# BeautifulSoup Object is different from request content

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I make a call to get function in Python using requests module. I pass this request content to BeautifulSoup. But when I print this BeautifulSoup object it is quite different from request content. Some of the tags are missing. Some of them are repeated. Why does it happen like that? For example:

```
req1=requests.get(url,headers)
print req1.content
s1=BeautifulSoup(req1.content)
print s1
```

Answer (score 1):

At least, this is because HTML can be not perfectly-formed and `BeautifulSoup`'s [underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) would make an attempt to fix it. The behavior varies  from parser to parser, see more at:

- [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)